# Nginx/Lua behaving strangely

Tags: nginx, server, lua, lua-table, openresty

I am a Lua newbie and I am trying to call a shared object (go code) from Lua which is basically authentication code, if the verification succeeds routing happens to upstream else forbidden is thrown, however, I am seeing a strange behavior, whenever I do a CURL after Nginx reload, authentication happens successfully and Nginx routes to upstream however every subsequent CURL results in the following error.

```
020/08/14 15:12:53 [error] 187#187: *18 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: 
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/auth.lua:18: cannot change a protected metatable
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
```

Auth.lua file

```
-- auth.lua
local ffi = require("ffi")

local im = ffi.load("/lib.so")

ffi.cdef([[
 typedef long long GoInt64;
 typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
 typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
 typedef struct { const char *p; GoInt n; } GoString;
 extern GoInt VerifyToken(GoString p0);

]]);


local accessToken = string.sub(ngx.var.http_Authorization,8)
local typeString = ffi.metatype("GoString", {})
--- above line throwing error ^^^^
local  accessTokenString= typeString(accessToken, string.len(accessToken))

local result = im.VerifyToken(accessTokenString)

if tonumber(result)==1LL then
 -- we are ok here and proceed to route to upstream
else
 ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

Can any one tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: "The association with a metatable is permanent and cannot be changed afterwards.". You use `ffi.metatype` with empty metatable, I guess `ffi.typeof` is more suitable here.

Comment: It should work too: `local accessTokenString = ffi.new("GoString", {accessToken, #accessToken})`

Comment: @un.def typeof works thanks a million